# Java checking if the your one card away from a royal flush

Tags: java

I'm trying to build a function that checks if a hand of cards (5 cards) is only 1 card away from a royal flush. I was able to implement a method to check to see if the hand was a royal flush. Here it is if its any help:

```
public boolean royalFlush(List<Card> cards) {
    for(int i = 0; i<cards.size(); i++) {
        if(i == 0 && cards.get(i).getValue() != 1) {
            return false;
        }else if(i != 0 && cards.get(i).getValue()!=10){
            return false;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0;i<cards.size()-1; i++) {
        if(cards.get(i).getSuit() !=cards.get(i+1).getSuit()) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

This function assumes that the hand is already sorted with the ace starting first, than king, queen, jack and finally 10. It also assumes that the total number of cards in a hand is 5. It is safe to assume that the royal flush hand will always be sorted that way in any input. In my Card.java class I have enums for the suit and rank:

```
public static enum Suit {
    DIAMOND, HEART, SPADE, CLUB
};
public static enum Rank {
    TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING, ACE
};
```

So the getValue method if the if statement basically converts the rank to the actual int. So for instance Rank Two is 2 and when rank is TEEN, JACK, QUEEN, or KING the value is 10.

When you create a card you give it a rank and a suit..Example:

```
Card card = new Card(Card.Rank.JACK, Card.Suit.HEART))
```

Can anyone help me with a function that takes in a list of cards and determines if it's one away from a royal flush...and if so it will return the card that prevents the deck form being a royal flush.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Unfortunately, SO is not a code writing service. Maybe something like have a List that contains the 5 Royal Flush cards, and check that 4 of them match from the user's hand.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?  Seems like the logic is straightforward enough.  You have a collection of 5 objects, and you have a set of 5 known values.  If 4 distinct values in that are are present in the collection of 5 objects, you're one card away.

Answer (score 0):

Your existing royalFlush method doesn't pay attention to how many cards are being passed, so one option to check if you're one card away would be :

```
boolean oneCardAway = (royalFlush(myHand) && myHand.size()==4);
```

but in reality, you can only have a Royal Flush with 5 cards so you might add that validation to your method.

Comment: You can assume that a hand for sure consists of 5 cards